# Does add() on LinkedBlockingQueue notify waiting threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, queue

I have a consumer thread taking elements from a `LinkedBlockingQueue`, and I make it sleep manually when it's empty. I use `peek()` to see if the queue empty because I have to do stuff before sending the thread to sleep, and I do that with `queue.wait()`.

---

So, when I'm in another thread and `add()`an element to the queue, does that automatically notify the thread that was `wait()`ing on the queue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does. Or rather, it does using a more-efficient internal lock object and not the outer queue object's lock; if you want to sleep until something arrives in the queue, do a blocking `take()`. (If you have other things to do while waiting, consider whether a blocking queue is the correct way of receiving messages from elsewhere.)

Comment: It actually has two locks internally, one handling notification of the queue-empty case and the other of the queue-full case. They're `private` — with good reason — so use the API as it is meant to be used.